# RealVNC answer file installation problems

Tags: realvnc

How can I install RealVNC using something that answers the file installation prompts silently?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice write up about doing an unattended (silent) install of RealVNC on the [RealVNC Knowledge Base](http://kb.realvnc.com/questions/2/How+do+I+script+an+unattended%7B47%7Dremote+installation+of+VNC+Enterprise+Edition).

The process is well documented and they make use of [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).